# Scaling SignalR with SQL server - how often can we clear data?

Tags: sql-server, signalr, signalr-backplane

I'm looking to write a scaled out SignalR application using SQL Server, using [this article](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server) as a guidline. After doing some testing, it looks like the table `Messages_0` in the SignalR database that I created (per the article) could get pretty big.

What I'm wondering is, how often can this data be cleared out? I see there is an `InsertedOn` column so I would think after day or two the data wouldn't be relevant anymore. Is there any documentation or guidelines on this?

I'm wondering if I could just set up a job that would clear out anything older than a week just to prevent the table from getting too big over time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation seems to suggest (albeit briefly), that you should not delete rows yourself.

> SignalR manages the tables. As long as your application is deployed, don't delete rows, modify the table, and so forth.

Take a look at: [Scaleout With SignalR - asp.net](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-sql-server)

Comment: oh wow - in the same article I linked to. Apparently I should read the full article before asking my questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for the same thing, and I did read the suggestion in the documentation, but I was wondering if SignalR would clean up by itself in that case, and when.

I found the answer here: [How to cleanup SignalR SQL database](https://forums.asp.net/t/1982251.aspx?How%20to%20cleanup%20SignalR%20SQL%20database)
Which points to the github repository, where you can see how SignalR automatically cleans the tables when reaching a hardcoded limit.
See github code here: [SignalR SQL automatical clean-up](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SqlServer/send.sql#L39)

Thought it might be useful to add to this question, for anyone searching the same question.